# Redux: mapStateToProps is rendering twice

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux

I have started learning Redux recently, and something is bugging me.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { connect, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import Modal from "../Modal/Modal";
import history from "../../utils/history";
import { fetchPost } from "../../actions";

const PostDelete = ({ match, post }) => {
  const postId = match.params?.id;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchPost(postId));
  }, [dispatch]);
  return (
    <Modal
    />
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state, { match }) => {
  console.log("MSTP", state.posts[match.params?.id]) // <== CONSOLED TWICE !!
  return { post: state.posts[match.params?.id] };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {})(PostDelete);
```

When I navigate to this using **react-router**, as per my understanding:

1. MSTP should be called first(which fetches the post from the store)
2. Then useEffect() fetches the post(just in case user directly opens this page)
3. It dispatches the action which changes the state
4. This re-renders the MSTP again

Is there a way to get around this? Is this a bad approach or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explanation

First of all I'd like to say your understanding of what's happening is correct. From the [official react-redux documentation](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate#connect-extracting-data-with-mapstatetoprops) it describes that `mapStateToProps` is called *every time* the store is updated.

This is ok if you have a fairly simple `mapStateToProps` object to compute, but can cause performance degradations if you're doing something more intensive. For intensive cases I'd recommend using a memoized selector, which will just return the previously calculated `mapStateToProps` value, without doing any new computations, if no relevant changes were made to the store. A good library for achieving this is [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect).

Even with a memoized selector, your `console.log('MSTP')` statement will be printed, but the underlying computation will be quicker.

#### Code Example

Consider the following example.

1. Component is rendered for the first time
2. useEffect fetches the post and updates the store at `state.posts` (relevant to this component)
3. Some other component updates the redux state, at an irrelevant part to this component, e.g. `state.comments`

Here's the code and console output **BEFORE** using a memoized selector

```
const intensivePostsFormatting = (state) => {
   console.log('Formatting Posts');
   // do some stuff with state.posts
   return formattedPosts;
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ match, state }) => {
  console.log('MSTP');
  return {
    posts: intensivePostsFormatting(state)
   }
}

// Console Output:
// MSTP
// Formatting Posts
// MSTP
// Formatting Posts
// MSTP
// Formatting Posts
```

Here's the code and output **AFTER** using a memoized selector

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

const intensivePostsFormatting = (posts) => {
   console.log('Formatting Posts');
   // do some stuff with posts
   return formattedPosts;
}

const postsSelector = createSelector(
   state => state.posts,
   posts => intensivePostsFormatting(posts)
)

const mapStateToProps = ({match, state }) => {
  console.log('MSTP');
  return {
    posts: postsSelector(state)
   }
}

// Console Output:
// MSTP
// Formatting Posts
// MSTP
// Formatting Posts
// MSTP
```

Note that the difference between the before and after, is that "Formatting Posts" is logged 3 times in the "before" example and 2 times in the "after" example. This is because using a memoized selector allowed us to skip computing the formatted posts when a change to something other than `state.posts` was made.

Comment: This made it very clear. Thanks a lot for taking time to explain all of this!

Comment: No problem, happy to help :)